# Ingress path issue

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I have deployed my application in aks environment and I'm using [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

- when I access my URL like this https://allure-report.com/200/ than I can access my application but
- when I access my URL like this
  https://allure-report.com/200  ( without / at end ) there is a white Blank page coming

my ingress rule file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: allure-ingress
  namespace: allure-report
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: allure-report.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: allure-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /200/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - allure-report.com
    secretName: allure-ingress-secret
```

Thank you in advance

tried :

- /200(/|$)(.*)
- /200(/|/?.*)

above both are not even working for /200/ path

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

You use `pathType: Prefix` in your ingress.

While Ingress API allows users to specify different ***pathType*** on Ingress object.

pathType `Exact` and `Prefix` should allow only a small set of characters, pathType `ImplementationSpecific` allows any characters, as it may contain regexes, variables and other features that may be specific of the Ingress Controller being used.

You may use pathType `ImplementationSpecific`  and try also `/200(/|$)(.*)`

Comment: no not working 
it stopped working for /200/ path also